# How to add proxy in Selenium

Tags: go, selenium-webdriver, proxy

I am trying to add proxies. They are working in other programs, but not in Selenium. It is https proxy with a username and password, so I tryed to use an SSL and HTTP as type. Username and password has only SOCKS here, so I tryed to use them. Here is a part of code.

```
168.80.202.181:8000
Login
Tvh123
Password
u1239C
Type
HTTPS
```

```
import (
    "github.com/tebeka/selenium"
    "github.com/tebeka/selenium/chrome"
)

    // ...
    caps := selenium.Capabilities{}
    caps.AddChrome(chrome.Capabilities{Args: []string{
        "window-size=1920x1080",
    }})
    caps.AddProxy(selenium.Proxy{
        Type:          selenium.Manual,
        HTTP:          "168.80.202.181",
        HTTPPort:      8000,
        SOCKSUsername: "Tvh123",
        SOCKSPassword: "u1239C",
    })
    // ...
```

I tryed to change HTTP on SSL and SOCKS (and I set a version 4 and 5)

Comment: I'm not familiar with `selenium`, but AFAIK, Chrome does not support HTTP proxy with username:password. See https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-settings. FYI, [puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.authenticate/) and [chromedp](https://github.com/chromedp/examples/blob/master/proxy/main.go) rely on the [Fetch.authRequired](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/#event-authRequired) event to provide the proxy credentials.

Comment: I also tried to use SOCKS5, but it also doesn't work